# Sample size to test small proportion

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, sample-size, proportion

What sample size $n$ is required to test the following binomial probability in a single sample:

$H_0: p \leq p_0$

$H_1: p > p_0$

Is there an exact, robust formula to calculate $n$ in terms of $\alpha$, $\beta$, expected probability $p_0$, and effect size (ideally Odds Ratio), when $p_0$ is very small (e.g., <10^-12)?

Comment: Related:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204391/what-is-the-best-test-to-measure-deviations-from-tiny-proportions

Answer (score 2):

Let $X \sim \mathcal{Binom}(n,p)$. Under the assumption that the value of $p$ is the very small $p_0$ (as an example I use $p_0 = 10^{-6}$). We will not be able to do a meaningful test unless $n$ is very large, so if needed $X\sim \mathcal{Poisson}(n p_0)$ will be a very good approximation. The waiting time to thhe first success will be a geometrical variable $N$ with pmf (probability mass function) $(1-p)^{n-1}\cdot p$ with expected value $1/p$, so with our $p_0$ that is $10^6$, so we must plan for a rather large sample!

But even then there is a risk (if our assumption is true) that we will not see any success, so we must plan for that. Then remember *the rule of three* [Revisiting the Rule of Three](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/497548/revisiting-the-rule-of-three), if we did not see any success then an approximate confidence interval (CI) is $[0,1/3n]$. If you want such an interval to be no larger that $[0,p_0]$ you must plan for $1/3n = p_0$, that is, a sample size of about $333 333$.

This is admittedly only a back-of-the-envelope calculation, I will add some formal power calculations later.