# What is the best test to measure deviations from tiny proportions?

Tags: binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

What is the best (most reliable and robust) test to measure deviations from tiny expected proportions (e.g., p0 < 10^-6) in a huge sample?

Binomial? Poisson? Negative binomial? Something else?

How do these tests differ?  What are their limitations?

And how to calculate power/sample size for each test?

Answer (score 1):

I'm surely not the best one to answer this, but since the question has been unanswered for months, I'll try.

Since you are asking about proportions, I understand your process is a binomial. Then I would go for a binomial.

A Poisson variable would just be an approximation to binomial, and since proportions are tiny and sample is huge, we can expect a Poisson approximation to work well. Then, you could use a Poisson if it made your computations easier.

The other usual approximation to binomial is normal distribution, but with such a tiny proportion you would need an extremely big sample for the normal to be a good approximation - I mean a sample quite bigger than the inverse of the tiny probability.

Negative binomial is about time between successes, and if you are analysing proportion of successes I don't see how could negative binomial help.

In summary, I'd say use binomial, and approximate it by Poisson if (and only if) it makes your work easier.