# Tools for reporting sample size that contains the percentage of the population

Tags: sample-size, sample, population, percentage, population-attributable-fraction

If we have a recorded percentage (statistic) on a population, if we take random samples we might not encounter the percentage till e.g. even we exhaust the population.
E.g. a box with $500000$ balls of which $25000$ ($5$%) of them are red and the rest are all white.
My question is what is min/max number of a sample to consider we will be able to see that $5$% of red balls we know exists in the larger population? And not specifically for $500000$ but any population larger than $50000$.
Are there any online tools/tables already available that can provide the sizes for any number $n$ of a population?
If there is also a margin of error that is ok too as long as it is configurable/reported

Comment: Welcome to CV, Jim. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "we will be able to see that 5% of red balls we know exists in the larger population"?  This doesn't make much sense in English and has many reasonable, entirely different interpretations ranging from "high chance of observing at least one red ball in the sample" to "being certain exactly 5% of the balls in the sample are red," with many intermediate versions of these criteria possible.

Comment: @whuber: I mean the following. If we start checking a sample of $100$ we might get $0$ red balls. Similar for the next $100$ etc till we already explored a very large number of the population. At this point till someone starts exhausting the samples or increase the sample size they would not be able to conclude that there is a percentage of red balls at all in the population. So my question is exactly what is the min sample size one must use to not end up in such case. Does this help?

Comment: I think so.  Search for the [Rule of 3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=rule+of+3).  Maybe the thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/497548/revisiting-the-rule-of-three answers your question?  If not, reading it ought to help you refine your problem statement.

Comment: @whuber:just to clarify. I am not interested in the math behind calculating it. I am interesting in some tool that I can plugin the values and get the result. Or some existing table with already calculated sizes

Comment: It is crucial to understand the problem before trying to use any such tool.

Comment: @whuber: I am not sure what you mean. I was looking for something equivalent to e.g. prime tables that precalculate things. I am not really interested in the math behind the calculation. Only a way to specific population size e.g. 125000, the ratio in the population and margin of error e.g. 2% or 5% and get back the min/max meaningful sample sizes

Comment: @whuber: I meant "Only a way to *set/provide* specific population size...."

Comment: The difficulty is that your problem is not fully specified.  Studying some of the posts I referred you to will show you what is missing and give you a good foundation to conceptualize the issues and to understand what any particular app or table offers. Otherwise you are basically asking us to teach you sampling theory.